# In firebase, how do I retrieve the uid that was automatically created when pushing?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how do I retrieve the uid (automatically created) as the id of the object itself, so later I can find the object and update its child properties (if any). Thanks.

For example:

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(OBJ_CHILD).push().setValue(friendlyObject);  
// I know this process will create a uid for the newly pushed object, and I want to get the uid of the bucket.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ref = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(OBJ_CHILD).push();

... // create hashmap to push (friendlyObject)
ref.setValue(friendlyValue);

String uid = ref.getKey();
```

see more here - https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html under
 `Getting the Unique ID Generated by push()`